# Using other layouts inside a Grails GSP layout

Tags: grails, layout, gsp, reusability

I have a Grails 2.4.x app where ~80% of the pages use a `simple.gsp` layout, and the other pages are all stragglers that don't use any layout/templating at all. But they can't use `simple.gsp` because its contents don't apply to them.

I have a need to add a header nav to all of these pages (100%) and would like an elegant solution. Ideally, I could create a new layout, say, `awesome-header.gsp` that contains the header nav. Then:

- For any pages (again, ~20%) that *don't* use the `simple.gsp` layout, I would just have them use `awesome-header.gsp` directly; but then...
- I would just somehow reference/import/extend `simple.gsp` to (somehow) use `awesome-header.gsp`; which now allows the other ~80% pages to use the new header nav

Let's pretend that this is `simple.gsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            <g:layoutTitle default="Some App" />
        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Lots of stuff -->
        <g:layoutHead />
        <!-- Lots of stuff -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Lots of stuff -->
        <div id="page-content">
            <g:layoutBody />
        </div>
        <!-- Lots of stuff -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And let's pretend that this is `awesome-header.gsp`:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script id="awesome-header-bootstrap" src="/awesome-header/awesome-header-bootstrap-1.0.js"><script>
        <g:layoutBody />
    </body>
</html>
```

Pretty barebones. All I need this `awesome-header.gsp` layout to do is include a JS right at the top of the `<body>` element. For the purpose of this question, this JS script is "magic" and fetches the header nav magically for me.

- **How can reference/import/extend `simple.gsp` to use `awesome-header.gsp`?**
- I don't want the `awesome-header.gsp` to override any `title` or `header` content (either defined inside `simple.gsp` or in any of the straggler pages)

Any ideas how I could accomplish this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand, you want a hierarchy between *simple.gsp* and *awesome-header.gsp*. So you may look at this [link](http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2011/04/grails-goodness-applying-layouts-in.html) to help you to do that.

An other solution, maybe easier because there isn't a lot of modifications to do, is to use templates:

- Put all your HTML / JS code related to your awesome-header inside a template (let say *_awesome-header.gsp*, the '_' is important !)
- Simply put that line inside your 'simple' layout and inside all others pages which are not connected to your 'simple' layout: `<g:render template='awesome-header'/>`